# Hume Enquiry Concerning Human Understanding "Algebra, Geometry, and Arithmetic" from "senses and experience"?

Tags: epistemology, hume

Here are two quotes in Hume's *Enquiry Concerning Human Understanding*. They seem to contradict one another, and I want to know how/where Hume or his adherents reconcile them. I have not yet finished the *Enquiry*, but I have read significantly beyond where these quotes appear.

Section 1.5: *"But though our thought seems to possess this unbounded liberty, we shall find, upon a nearer examination, that it is really confined within very narrow limits, and that all this creative power of the mind amounts to no more than the faculty of compounding, transposing, augmenting, or diminishing the materials afforded us by the senses and experience."*

Section 4.1: [discussing "Geometry, Algebra, and Arithmetic"] *"Propositions of this kind are discoverable by the mere operation of thought, without dependence on what is any where existent in the universe."*

It looks like he says first that (1) all ideas are produced from senses/experience and then that (2) some ideas are not produced from senses/experience.

Am I misreading these quotes? Or is there an accepted [Humean] reconciliation of the apparent contradiction? Or is this pair of quotes just accepted as a gaffe?

I am a displaced STEM kid taking *Introduction to Philosophy*, and the class is reading from the Oxford World's Classics paperback edition, 2007. Thanks for helping me understand!

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the user!

Comment: "*All the objects of human reason or enquiry may naturally be divided into two kinds, to wit, relations of ideas, and matters of fact. Of the first kind are the sciences of Geometry, Algebra, and Arithmetic... discoverable by the mere operation of thought*". Math does not concern ideas as such, only relations among them produced by "compounding, transposing, augmenting, or diminishing", i.e. "the mere operation of thought".

Comment: So "propositions" which are "relations of ideas" are not produced from sense experience, and I am reading the first excerpt wrong? (1) is not right?

Comment: Correct. [Hume's relations of ideas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hume%27s_fork#Relations_of_ideas_and_matters_of_fact) are close to what Kant called "analytic *a priori*", definitional/conventional consequences.

Comment: You are correct that there is an apparent contradiction between the two places. On a mere textual level, this is not usually seen a genuine contradiction, because in section 4.1 Hume exploits, as @Conifold remarked, a distinction between knowledge based on ideas, and knowledge based on relations of ideas. This distinction is missing in the preliminary section 1.5. This is usually read as a development of thought during the text, rather than a genuine contradiction. On a deeper level, later philosophers, notably Kant, did detect a related kind of contradiction in Hume's thought -

Comment: - But this was, again, not a contradiction on the mere textual level.